# Python - how to use docstring and code examples of a function

Tags: python, function, documentation, docstring

```
def sum_prime():
digit_Sum([1, 2, 3]) == 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
digit_Sum([5, 6, 7]) == 5 + 6 + 7 = 18
digit_Sum([100, 12, 1]) == 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 5
```

**The digit sum function should return the sum of all the digits in a given list of integers.
what is wrong with the function signature and doc string?
**
[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIUl9.png)

Comment: How I can edit the question ?
I new user on stack overflow
I want put picture !

Comment: Please attach code! Use ``` before and after it like this : ``` code ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding docstring:

There is no docstring in that function, please refer to [Docstring Docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

In addition, the explanations given are about `digit_Sum`, where is the method is `sum_prime`.

Either way `digit_Sum([100, 12, 1]) == 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 5` isn't a clear example.

Here is an example of how docstring could have been written:

```
def sum_prime(list):
    """Gets a list and does <OPERATION> on it

    Works with list of numbers:
    
    >>> sum_prime([5, 5, 1])
    11
    
    """
    <YOUR CODE HERE>
```

2. Regarding the signature:

From what you describe the `sum_prime` should get a list parameter - so it's signature should be like `def sum_prime(list):`.

Hope it helped!

Comment: thanks so much 
I want to send you a picture for this example? How I can send you a message?

Comment: Please look at the image